# AttributeError: type object 'PhotoImage' has no attribute 'configure'

Tags: python-3.x, database, tkinter, pycharm, ssms

I am creating a log in form in python using PYCHARM.I am trying to define a function that will allow me to click the eye icon to hide or unhide the password as it is typed. When the eye button is clicked, I wanted the eye icon to change to a closed eye icon. When I ran the program, it does run, however when I click the eye button to hide the password, I get an error in the output. Can you please help me figure out what I should do.

**Below is my code **  (PYTHON3)

```
import tkinter #Need this library to create widget log in popup
from tkinter import messagebox, END
import pypyodbc as odbc
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage

\#Front end design of log in database

\#GUI PART

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("Database Login")
window.geometry('990x660+50+50')
bg_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='whew.jpg')

\#Functionality Part

def user_enter(event):
    if usernameEntry.get() == 'Username':
     usernameEntry.delete(0, END)

def pass_enter(event):
    if passwordEntry.get() == 'Password':
     passwordEntry.delete(0, END)

def hide():
     open_eye_image.configure(file='closeyeeeeee fr.png')

\#create widget

bgLabel = tkinter.Label(window, image=bg_Image)

heading = tkinter.Label(window, text='USER LOGIN', bg='white',  fg='#FF81C0', font=('Microsoft Yahei UI Light', 23))

usernameEntry = tkinter.Entry(window, width=25, font=('Microsoft Yahei UI Light', 11), bd=0, fg='#FF81C0')

passwordEntry = tkinter.Entry(window, width=25, font=('Microsoft Yahei UI Light', 11), bd=0, fg='#FF81C0')

open_image = PhotoImage(file='openeyeeeee fr (1).png')

eyeButton = tkinter.Button(window, image=open_image, bd=0, bg='white', activebackground='white', cursor='hand2', command=hide)

\#Different tkinter geometry - pack, place, and grid

bgLabel.place(x=0, y=0)

heading.place(x=630, y=200)

usernameEntry.place(x=620, y=300)

passwordEntry.place(x=620, y=350)

usernameEntry.insert(0, 'Username')

passwordEntry.insert(0, 'Password')

usernameEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', user_enter)

passwordEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', pass_enter)

tkinter.Frame(window, width=215, height=2, bg='#FF81C0').place(x=620, y=320)

tkinter.Frame(window, width=215, height=2, bg='#FF81C0').place(x=620, y=370)

eyeButton.place(x=810, y=345)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should `open_eye_image` be `open_image` instead inside `hide()`? The error tells you obviously that `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` class does not have `configure()`.

Answer (score 0):

This code toggles the image of a button :

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

hidden = True

def toggle_image():
    global hidden
    image = open_eye if hidden else closed_eye
    password_button.config(image=image)
    hidden = not hidden

w = tk.Tk()
open_eye = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='eye_open.png')
closed_eye = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='eye_closed.png') 

password_button = tk.Button(w, command=toggle_image, image=closed_eye)
password_button.pack()

w.mainloop()
```